# 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'date_start'. Django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am new to Django. In my project I want to filter all the room with available status, then I want start_date to be updated to the current datetime. But I am getting the following error:

```
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'start_date'
```

I have the following class in the models.py:

```
class RoomStatus(models.Model):

room = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

  class RoomStatusChoices(models.IntegerChoices):

  AVAILABLE = 1
  UNAVAILABLE = 2

  room_status = 
  models.SmallIntegerField(choices=RoomStatusChoices.choices, 
  default=RoomStatusChoices.AVAILABLE)

  start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

In serializers.py I wrote an update with this code

```
  available_rooms = RoomStatus.objects.filter(room=room, 
  room_status=RoomStatusChoices.AVAILABLE)
  print(available_rooms)  
  available_rooms.start_date = max(available_rooms.start_date, datetime.now())
```

The result of print(available_rooms) is <QuerySet []>

Can someone help me? thanks indvance.

Comment: available_rooms is a query set which is an iterable of room objects (in your case its empty). the list doesn't have a `.start_date` attribute because its not a room object. each elemnt of the list might have the attribute but the list (or more correctly - the query set) doesnt.

Comment: @NotSoShabby- should I add strat_date to the qureyset?

Comment: You have to get the start_date from a element of queryset, something like available_rooms[0].start_date

Comment: @Luiz- it  is not working still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.db.models import Max
start_date_max = available_rooms.aggregate(Max('start_date'))
```

Now `star_date_max` will be a dectionary like `{'start_date__max': date(.....)}` ;confirm that .. print it out and see.

now to seta all `start_date` of the objects in the queryset..

```
new_start_date = star_date_max["start_date__max"]
available_rooms.update(start_date=new_start_date)
```

should do the job.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I could solve the probleem with using for loop: for  available_room in  available_rooms: